# http header regex match apache

Tags: apache-2.4, regex

I have a header in apache that is too long, so I want to turn it into a subset. The header is a string and I'm trying to get it to become this subset: WANTED_SUBSTRING_MATCH(everything in between) [but not the first colon]. which is in regex: `/wanted_substring_match(.+)[^:]/`

Is it possible to achieve this in apache? I've been trying to get `<If>` to work to no avail. I have also tried: `<If %{MY-Header} =~ /wanted_substring_match(.+)[^:]/>` but it doesn't match... this is likely because the `=~` keyword means an exact match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be %{HTTP:MY-Header} in an Apache Expression to match your header. And the (.+) should go after the [^:] to match anything except a colon.

Comment: it looks like req('MY-Header') also works. the regex doesn't work though. So I have: `<If "req('MY-Header') =~ /(.+)/">` to test it out and it doesn't match! Why is that? `m#(.+)#` also doesn't work

Comment: This MY-Header is actually sent by the browser? The <If> statement is in a section which is actually hit?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that it is sent. The if statement is executed if I do `!~` instead...

Comment: Which would imply that the header is seen as empty string. So =~ /^$/ should match also. Is there anything special about the request handling. Is it a proxy or rewrite with mod_headers doing stuff?

Comment: but editing the header works? for instance, `RequestHeader edit* MY-Header "-" ""` does indeed remove all dashes from MY-Header

Comment: I just mentioned mod_headers because <If> evaluates early and I don't know what happens if you mix mod_headers with <If> on a header. You can maybe influence that by the "early" keyword in mod_headers.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the header directly without an `<If/>`:

```
# replace 'My-Header:want_foo:bar' with 'My-Header:want_foo' 
RequestHeader edit My-Header ^(want_[^:]*).* $1

# alternative: replace colon and any following characters with an empty string
#RequestHeader edit My-Header :.* ""
```

Example with `<If>`:

```
# forbid access to headers starting with `want_` 
# containing NOT a colon anywhere 
<If "! %{HTTP:My-Header} =~ /^want_.*:/">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Comment: I do an if because I want to use a special apache function on the new header, is that possible to achieve here? The function shouldnt be called on the old header if there is no regex match

Comment: Example added. You can reverse the `<If>` by removing the exclamation mark.